# Changing required property left field blank

Tags: swift, realm

I have object `Company` that previously used an optional property `name`. Now I needed to change it to not be null, so I changed it from

```
@objc dynamic var name: String?
```

to

```
@objc dynamic var name = ""
```

The problem is that now all company names are reporting as empty strings. The realm itself does have valid values in it. If I change the code back to the optional method it does have their values. Other places that have always been required strings are not returning empty strings. What is causing this?

Comment: Maybe you should use migration to assign default value to nil fields and assign current value for non-nil fields?

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#updating-values

Comment: @Mika I thought it wouldn't have mattered since it was the same field name and type. Thanks!